# every entity implement interface?

Tags: c#, interface, architecture, entity

Currently, am working on architecture of application, I have many entities in my project i.e student teacher university, I was wondering about is it a good practice that all entity must implement interface. This will help me in dependency injection?  What is the best practice from architecture point of view.

```
 public interface IMyEntity
    {
          //an empty interface
    }
public class Student:IMyEntity
{

}
public class Teacher:IMyEntity
{

}
```

//hi I can deal with every object which implement IMyEntity

```
void Display(IMyEntity entity) //this function can be in some class
{
    // if IMyEntity is teacher behave like a teacher
    // if IMyEntity is student behave like sutdent
}
```

I know interface is a contract, but from architecture point of view it is best practice? I know my `IMyEntity` interface is empty.

Comment: student teacher university all are entities real world object. does it make sense every entity must contains a weight mass or shape? I can keep these things in my interface?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  If in this case Student and Teacher have some common functionality then a shared interface would be one approach to take.

```
public void Display(IUniPerson person)
{
    var name = person.Name; // Everyone, student or teacher, has a name
    ...
}
```

However, the example you give seems to suggest that this is not the case, and the Display method will attempt to treat the passed in instance of IMyEntity differently depending on it's type.  In that case, you may be better with 2 Display methods with different parameters.

```
public void Display(ITeacher teacher) { // teacher processing }
public void Display(IStudent student) { // student processing }
```

tl:dr version:  implement an interface across multiple classes if it makes sense for those classes to implement related methods and functions, rather than just as a blanket rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **decoupling 2 or more classes is a good taste in terms of developing and it really helps maintaining the code** in a long run.

Consider the follow scenario:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objA = new A();
    var objB = new B(objA);
}

public class A {}

public class B 
{
  public B(A obj)
  {
    //Logic Here
  }
}
```

The problem with this code it's that **it's strongly coupled**, class B needs class A to be instanced and do it's business.

This is not a problem if you are sure that B is never going to have some drammatic change.

Now if we want to decouple it we can make a first improvement implementing an interface like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objA = new A();
    var objB = new B(objA);
}

public interface IA()
{
    //TODO
}

public class A : IA {}

public class B 
{
  public B(IA obj)
  {
    //Logic Here
  }
}
```

It looks quite better what **we still have a couplation problem** in the Main, so at this point we will have to implement a Dependency Injection with a IOC like [**Ninject**](http://www.ninject.org/), and our code will be like to something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var objB = new B();
}

public interface IA()
{
    //TODO
}

public class A : IA {}

public class B 
{
  public B(IA obj)
  {
    //Logic Here
  }
}
```

Yes, that looks good. We have **completely removed the couplation** problem and it will be quite easy if in the future we just need to take A, delete it and replace it wich something new more cool.

Obviously **overkilling it's a bad practice** and I belive DI must be used only after carefuly planning to avoid useless implementations.

For example if I have a class C which has some basic operations, and I am sure that it will never change or have some drammatic need to update i can avoid DI.

### So do you have to implement interfaces on every model in your project?

Well I don't think each model in your project needs to implements an interface or DI, just think about it and see **where it can be useful and where it's just overkilling**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes do it like this, it is the best practise. This gives you the advantage of polymorphism. You should do it in better way in current context is not good, because `Student` is not a `Teacher`. If you want to share common interface you should define it as: `IUniversityMember`. Here an example for your case which I think will make it clear.

```
public interface IUniversityMember
{
   //... here common fields between `Teacher` and `Student`
   string Name{ get; set;}
   string Gender { get; set;}
}

//after that

public interface IStudent
{
    int GetGPA();
    int CreditsToPass {get; private set;}
}

public interface ITeacher
{
   int WorkedHours {get; set;}
   decimal PayPerHour {get; private set;}
}

public class BiologicalStudent: IUniversityMember, IStudent
{
    public int CreditsToPast {get; private set;}

    public BiologicalStudent ()
    {
        CreditsToPast  = 5;
    }
    //stuff
    public int GetGPA()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}

public class MathStudent: IUniversityMember, IStudent
{
    public int CreditsToPast {get; private set;}

    public BiologicalStudent ()
    {
        CreditsToPast  = 9;
    }

    public int GetGPA()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class BiologicalTeacher: IUniversityMember, ITeacher
{
     public int WorkedHours { get; set;}
     public decimal PayPerHour {get; private set;}

     public MathTeacher()
     {
         PayPerHour = 8;

     }
}

public class MathTeacher: IUniversityMember, ITeacher
{
     public int WorkedHours { get; set;}
     public decimal PayPerHour {get; private set;}

     public MathTeacher()
     {
         PayPerHour = 10;

     }
}
//Now if you have a university class

public class OxfordUniversity:IUniversity //can inherit interface too
{
     public int MinGAPForSchollarship {get; private set;}

     public OxfordUniversity()
     {
         MinGAPForSchollarship = 3;
     }

     public decimal PaySallary(ITeacher teacher)
     {
          return teacher.WorkedHours*teacher.PayPerHour;
     }

     public bool CheckForSchollarship(IStudent student)
     {
         int gpa = student.GetGPA();
         //do some checks

         if(gpa >= MinGAPForSchollarship)
            return true;

         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: ok, but if we see entity is a real world object so I can make an IEntity interface and rest of every entity should implement it? student teacher university all are real world objects, entity?

Comment: @bilal there is nothing common between University and Teacher. Think in such matter what is the common think between Student and Teacher. They are both IHuman and IUniversityMember. One university can have multiple teachers so you should have common interface ITeacher and again multiple Students with common interface IStudent. You can use only one interface for student and teacher, because one of them is taking salary, the other should take exams for an example. They have different purposes in the university.

Comment: @bilal About the University you can have multiple Universities so IUniversity interface. If you have School which also has teacher and students. You can define IEducationBuilding in which you can specify for an example the location of the building. In this case OxfordUniversity will inherit IEducationBuilding and IUniversity.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how .NET solved this, you can see some ambiguity.

For instance for every object has a function where you can ask for a string representation of the object: ToString(), even though for a string representation might not be a meaningful thing for a lot of classes

On the other hand, although it would be a useful function for every object to make a clone of itself they decided not to let every class implement ICloneable.

Whether it is wise for you to have (almost every) objects of your application a common interface depends on what you will do with this interface and the advantage of all objects implementing such an interface versus the burden of being obliged to implement the interface.

For example, if the entities you are talking about are database records, then it is very likely that every class will have some kind of ID. You could consider giving every class an interface with one get property that returns the value of the ID of the record.

```
public interface IID
{
    long ID {get;}
}
```

The advantage are multifold:

- You encourage every designer of database classes to implement the same type of primary key (in this case a long), and the same property name
- Advantage: it is easier to spot the ID of a record
- Advantage: it is easier to change the type of the ID
- Advantage: you know if you have a database record, you know some of the functions the record must have, without really knowing the type of the record.
- Even if the designer needs a different type, or different name, he can still create a special function to implement the interface:

  public class Person : IID
  {
      public int ID {get; set;}

  ```
  IID:ID {get {return this.ID;} }
  ```

  }

However, I suggest not to force interfaces to object for which it is not natural to have them. This has the advantage that you can't use these strange functions for object that have no real usage for them.

For example, most classes that represent some ordered numerical value have some notion of addition. Not only for integers and real numbers, but also for classes that represent a time span: 4 days and 23 hours + 1 day and 7 ours = 6 days and 6 hours. So for a time span addition is a useful interface

However, for a date, addition is not meaningful: 4th of july + 14 juillet = ?

So: Yes, implement interfaces for items that are natural to them. They force common naming and enable reuse. No, don't implement them for items that do not have a natural meaning for the functions.